# Java Thread Pool - try to generate n matrix

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'd love to help, I'm trying to create matrices and put them into a list using threadPool but I have some issues on the way.

i try to generate n matrices, and when i run the program i get this error:
Thread pool is interrupted due to an issue: null
and i try to solve this problem but i was not able to solve the problem.

this is my code:

main:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numOfThreads = 5;
        ThreadPool pool = new ThreadPool(numOfThreads);
        int numOfMatrices = 5;
        int diminesion = 3;

        GenerateMatrices generateMatrices = new GenerateMatrices(numOfMatrices, 
    diminesion);
        pool.execute(generateMatrices);

    }
}
```

ThreadPool class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
public class ThreadPool {
    private final int nThreads;
    private final PoolWorker[] threads;
    private final LinkedBlockingQueue queue;

    public ThreadPool(int nThreads) {
        this.nThreads = nThreads;
        queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
        threads = new PoolWorker[nThreads];

        for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
            threads[i] = new PoolWorker();
            threads[i].start();
        }
    }

    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.add(task);
            queue.notify();
        }
    }

    private class PoolWorker extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            Runnable task;

            while (true) {
                synchronized (queue) {
                    while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            queue.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            System.out.println("An error occurred while queue is 
    waiting: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    task = (Runnable) queue.poll();
                }

                // If we don't catch RuntimeException,
                // the pool could leak threads
                try {
                    task.run();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread pool is interrupted due to an  
    issue: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this my GenerateMatrices class:

```
import java.util.Queue;
public class GenerateMatrices implements Runnable {

    private int numOfMatrices;
    private int dimension;
    private Queue<int[][]> matrices;

    public GenerateMatrices(int n, int d) {
        numOfMatrices = n;
        dimension = d;
    }

    public Queue<int[][]> getMatrices() {
        return matrices;
    }

    public void run() {
        int[][] tempMatrix = new int[dimension][dimension];

        for (int k = 0; k < numOfMatrices; k++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < tempMatrix.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tempMatrix.length; j++) {
                    tempMatrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() + 1);
                }
            }
            matrices.add(tempMatrix);

            for (int i = 0; i < tempMatrix.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tempMatrix.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(tempMatrix[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thank you!!!!

Comment: change e.getMessage() to e.toString() to get information about the RuntimeException. Better yet, set a breakpoint at the catch, and run it in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you get `NullPointerException` because you do not initialize property `matrices` in `GenerateMatrices` class.

Also as of now you program still generates matrices in one thread because you submit only one `Runnable` to your thread pool and that `Runnable` generates matrices in a `for-loop`